# How to compile and run C++0x with GCC/G++ in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: concurrency, c++11, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to figure out how to use the upcoming C++ release 0x. It should be available in GCC 4.3+ with using the gcc std=gnu++0x option.

My simple thread program using 0x compiles in Eclipse CDT with std=gnu++0x added in Project > properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Miscellaneous > Other flags.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void hello()
{
    cout << "Hello Concurrent World!" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "starting" << endl;
    thread t(hello);
    t.join();
    cout << "ending" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The program only prints "starting" and returns 0. Does anyone know why it does not run the hello function threaded?

Comment: Have you added the `-pthread` flag, to the linker and the compiler ?

Comment: Nice, adding -pthread flag to the linker and the compiler does it. Thanks alot.

Comment: Add this as an answer so I can vote on it!

Comment: There is no such thing in "C/C++ Build / Settings" as "Miscellaneous". There is a greyed out drop-down list with "Default" in it, a greyed-out button labeled "Manage Configurations" and a pair of tabs: Binary Parsers and Error Parsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use threads you also need to link against the threading library.
In case you haven't done that add `-lpthread` to your command line or in your case to other flags field.

The command line execute (visible in your console window in eclipse) should look like this:

`gcc -std=gnu++0x -lpthread <source_file_name>.cc`